# Is it possible to pipe binary data into dump_syms of breakpad

Tags: linux, pipe, google-breakpad

Google's `dump_syms` program requires an input file and an output file to write the symbolicated file such as:

```
$ dump_syms ./test.so > test.so.sym
```

I have the binary of the `test.so` in the memory buffer. It doesn't play well with performance if I first write the binary to a temp file then feed it to the `dump_syms` then delete this temp source.

Is it possible to somehow directly pipe the binary data into the `dump_syms` in order to bypass the file system? I believe there must be a way maybe from Linux's native piping perspective to do this.

I know that the best way would be for the `dump_syms` to support piping, but I suppose it doesn't have this feature. Considering this, if there are any tip to, perhaps, modify the dump_syms to accept the pipe, I would love to hear that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "[named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)," then pass its name (which will be a path on the filesystem) to `dump_syms`.  Whether `dump_syms` will still work I can't say, because it may require random access which the pipe will not support.

Alternatively, if you can control where in memory you store the buffer in the first place, you could `mmap` a file, use that memory region to store the data, then give the name of that memory-mapped file to `dump_syms`.

Comment: Sounds nice. I will try and comment back. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Voted up the answer though it hasn't helped eventually. First, named piping isn't suitable for `dump_syms` because it needs to map the source file into the memory via `mmap` which isn't possible in named pipe's case. Second, using the memory mapping in Node.js isn't straightforward and implies blocking operations. The only way possible I think right now is by directly modifying the `breakpad`'s source code to read the piped data.

Comment: @Eye.   OK.  I guess the "crazy" optimized solution would be to get the functionality you need as a library instead of a separate executable; then you could simply operate on the memory you already have.  Might not be easy though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Currently though we don't have resources to spend time on porting breakpad into Node.js NPM module. That would be the best solution I'm sure.